# What could stop my jetty process at "fixed" times?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jetty

I have a service which runs under jetty 9.4.9 on an AWS machine. This service is being stopped every 25 hours at exactly the same time. It's really baffling me how this is possible. See the log files for instance

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jetty jetty 13406811 Jun 27 23:59 2019_06_27.jetty.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jetty jetty  8999999 Jun 28 17:14 2019_06_28.jetty.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jetty jetty 19008243 Jun 30 19:14 2019_06_30.jetty.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jetty jetty  3398645 Jul  1 20:13 2019_07_01.jetty.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jetty jetty  7907061 Jul  2 21:14 2019_07_02.jetty.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jetty jetty  3067392 Jul  3 22:13 2019_07_03.jetty.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jetty jetty  6006241 Jul  4 23:13 2019_07_04.jetty.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jetty jetty  3467522 Jul  5 23:59 2019_07_05.jetty.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jetty jetty     5862 Jul  6 00:14 2019_07_06.jetty.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jetty jetty  8636414 Jul  9 23:59 2019_07_09.jetty.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jetty jetty  8110920 Jul 10 04:16 2019_07_10.jetty.log
```

I do a manual restart every day but at random times, so the actual up time of jetty is never the same. The log file sizes are quite different as you can see.

I checked background processes, cron jobs etc... nothing can explain this behaviour.

Has this ever happened to someone before? any hint as to what I should be looking for?

Comment: Do the logs indicate any kind of "shutdown" or "stop" or "stopping" at the end of the log file?

Comment: No, nothing in the logs at all. The log traces just stop without any error message.

Comment: In that case, something killed the process outright.  A shutdown/stop would produce many log entries indicating a proper shutdown occurred.